# EC2からRDB(postgresql)にマイグレーションできない

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

EC2のインスタンスとRDS(Postgresql)のインスタンスを作成し`$ php artisan migrate`コマンドでマイグレーションを実行したら以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "laravel-ci.ci0vniglmj5j.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.coim" to
   address: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public an
  d table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

.envファイル

```
#PostgreSQL
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=laravel-cixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=larasns
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

試したこと
ポート番号やホストの名前をチェック、RDSのセキュリティグループのInBoundに、EC2のセキュリティグループが登録されているか確認。

OS：Windows10

Comment: .coim ってなってるので .com のミスじゃないですか？

Comment: その通りでした！ありがとうございます。