# EC２でのマイグレーション（PostgreSQL）時にエラーが出てしまう。

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

[EC2からRDB(postgresql)にマイグレーションできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70263/ec2%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89rdbpostgresql%e3%81%ab%e3%83%9e%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b0%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)
こちらの質問の続きとなります。
AWS初心者です。EC2に接続しRDSのインスタンスに接続しマイグレーションを実行しようとしましたが以下のエラーが出ました。

**エラー**

```
 SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

.envファイル

```
#PostgreSQL
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=laravel-cixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=larasns
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

やはり.envファイルが間違っているのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。
OS：Windows10

追記
RDSの設定
データベースの作成方法：標準作成
エンジンのタイプ: PostgreSQL
バージョン: PostgreSQL 11.6-R1
テンプレート：無料枠
マスターユーザー名: postgres
パスワードの自動生成: チェックを入れる
DBインスタンスサイズ：バースト可能クラス (t クラスを含む)、db.t2.micro
パブリックアクセス可能: なし
VPCセキュリティグループ: 既存の選択
既存のVPCセキュリティグループ: laravel-ci-sg-for-private-server (defaultなし)
アベイラビリティーゾーン: 指定しない
データベースポート: 5432
最初のデータベース名: larasns
自動バックアップの有効化: チェックしない
Performance Insights を有効にする: チェックしない
拡張モニタリングの有効化: チェックしない

他指示があれば随時追加します。

Comment: 問題の切り分けのためにec2から疎通確認してみてはいかがでしょう。［参考］(https://oji-cloud.net/2019/10/04/post-3184/) これで繋がらないなら、AWS側の設定の不備もあるかも

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。TcpTestSucceeded       : Falseと出たのでAWS側の設定の不備と判断しました

Comment: となるとAwsで実施した設定の手順やコードをかいてもらうとより回答が得やすいでしょう